# Find and keep string in a specific postion and remove all other strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to find and keep all strings that are in between `<strong>string I want to keep</strong>` tag and remove all other text (includes `<strong></strong>`)

Is it possible to do it in Notepad++, please advise.

Comment: I'll just leave this here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find:

```
.*?<strong>(.*?)</strong>.*?
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

**NOTE** You should check `. matches newline` checkbox.

[image]

result:

[image]

Use `\1\n` if you want following as result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for assisting me! I applied your method and it worked almost perfectly, only thing is that there are still remaining text after the last found string, like this: <strong>this is the last found string</strong> we're the rest of document and we are still here.

Comment: @RonaldinhoState, Use `.*?<strong>(.*?)</strong>.*?|.*$` for pattern to remove trailing text.